# check if network bridge on windows is up and running

Tags: windows, networking

My setup has a network bridge setup where an ethernet and TAP-devices are running on a bridge. Everything worked fine, until recently the network bridge due to some unkown reason disappeared. It took me half a day to figure out, that this was the case.
Is there any command line to check if a network bridge of windows is still up and running?

Comment: `ping -S SourceAddr BridgeIP` ?

Comment: ip is randomly assigned, so i would need to know the ip addr before

Answer (score 0):

We can check if the virtual network adapter of TAP-devices is still existing manually, if so, we can create the network bridge between ethernet and virtual network adapter of TAP-devices.
If the virtual network adapter of TAP-devices is not existing, the network bridge between ethernet and TAP-devices must be not up and running. So we need to recreate the virtual network adapter of TAP-devices, then create the network bridge between ethernet and virtual network adapter of TAP-devices.
We can check it like this:
[image]